# Azure Managed Identity Token couldn't produce from local

Tags: azure, asp.net-core-webapi, azure-managed-identity

This is a continuation of the ticket [Restrict Access with Azure Managed Identity in .NET Core Web API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73680826/restrict-access-with-azure-managed-identity-in-net-core-web-api/73681039?noredirect=1#comment130113467_73681039) where I configured a .NET Core Web API to secured with user-assigned Azurre Managed Identity. This Web API has been deployed as https://epd-api.azurewebsites.net.

Now I have a locally running/debugging .NET Core WebApp trying to access the managed identity token for above azue deployed Web API as below.

```
 string userAssignedClientId = "<<managed-identity clientid>>"; 
    var credential = new DefaultAzureCredential(new DefaultAzureCredentialOptions { ManagedIdentityClientId=userAssignedClientId }); 
    var accessToken = await credential.GetTokenAsync(new TokenRequestContext(new[] { "https://epd-api.azurewebsites.net/.default" }));
 client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", accessToken.Token);
```

It's breaking at line 'credential.GetTokenAsync()' with below exceptionn message.

> AuthenticationFailedException: Azure CLI authentication failed due to
> an unknown error. See the troubleshooting guide for more information.
> https://aka.ms/azsdk/net/identity/azclicredential/troubleshoot ERROR:
> The command failed with an unexpected error. Here is the traceback:
> ERROR: Get Token request returned http error: 400 and server response:
> {"error":"invalid_resource","error_description":"AADSTS500011: The
> resource principal named https://epd-api.azurewebsites.net was not
> found in the tenant named DXC Production. This can happen if the
> application has not been installed by the administrator of the tenant
> or consented to by any user in the tenant. You might have sent your
> authentication request to the wrong tenant.\r\nTrace ID:
> b537e8c2-c1a8-44ff-a363-d162cd15e101\r\nCorrelation ID:
> 507df083-138c-4848-b446-40631732a181\r\nTimestamp: 2022-09-13
> 06:52:22Z","error_codes":[500011],"timestamp":"2022-09-13
> 06:52:22Z","trace_id":"b537e8c2-c1a8-44ff-a363-d162cd15e101","correlation_id":"507df083-138c-4848-b446-40631732a181","error_uri":"https://login.microsoftonline.com/error?code=500011"}
> Traceback (most recent call last):

Once I deployed my Web APP in Azure, the error message is different as below.

> Connection ID "15636497907840976997", Request ID
> "80000866-0000-d900-b63f-84710c7967bb": An unhandled exception was
> thrown by the application.
>
> Exception:  Azure.Identity.AuthenticationFailedException:
> ManagedIdentityCredential authentication failed: Service request
> failed. Status: 500 (Internal Server Error)
>
> Content:
>
> Headers: Date: Tue, 13 Sep 2022 07:39:11 GMT Server: Kestrel
> Transfer-Encoding: chunked X-CORRELATION-ID: REDACTED Content-Type:
> application/json; charset=utf-8
>
> See the troubleshooting guide for more information.
> https://aka.ms/azsdk/net/identity/managedidentitycredential/troubleshoot
> ---> Azure.RequestFailedException: Service request failed. Status: 500 (Internal Server Error)
>
> Content:
>
> Headers: Date: Tue, 13 Sep 2022 07:39:11 GMT Server: Kestrel
> Transfer-Encoding: chunked X-CORRELATION-ID: REDACTED Content-Type:
> application/json; charset=utf-8
>
> at Azure.Identity.ManagedIdentitySource.HandleResponseAsync(Boolean
> async, TokenRequestContext context, Response response,
> CancellationToken cancellationToken)    at
> Azure.Identity.ManagedIdentitySource.AuthenticateAsync(Boolean async,
> TokenRequestContext context, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
> at Azure.Identity.ManagedIdentityClient.AuthenticateAsync(Boolean
> async, TokenRequestContext context, CancellationToken
> cancellationToken)    at
> Azure.Identity.ManagedIdentityCredential.GetTokenImplAsync(Boolean
> async, TokenRequestContext requestContext, CancellationToken
> cancellationToken)    --- End of inner exception stack trace ---    at
> Azure.Identity.CredentialDiagnosticScope.FailWrapAndThrow(Exception
> ex, String additionalMessage)    at
> Azure.Identity.ManagedIdentityCredential.GetTokenImplAsync(Boolean
> async, TokenRequestContext requestContext, CancellationToken
> cancellationToken)    at
> Azure.Identity.ManagedIdentityCredential.GetTokenAsync(TokenRequestContext
> requestContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)    at
> Azure.Identity.DefaultAzureCredential.GetTokenFromSourcesAsync(TokenCredential[]
> sources, TokenRequestContext requestContext, Boolean async,
> CancellationToken cancellationToken)    at
> Azure.Identity.DefaultAzureCredential.GetTokenImplAsync(Boolean async,
> TokenRequestContext requestContext, CancellationToken
> cancellationToken)    at
> Azure.Identity.CredentialDiagnosticScope.FailWrapAndThrow(Exception
> ex, String additionalMessage)    at
> Azure.Identity.DefaultAzureCredential.GetTokenImplAsync(Boolean async,
> TokenRequestContext requestContext, CancellationToken
> cancellationToken)    at
> Azure.Identity.DefaultAzureCredential.GetTokenAsync(TokenRequestContext
> requestContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)    at
> ManagedIdentityWeb.Pages.IndexModel.OnGetAsync() in
> C:\Users\jmathews4\Source\Repos\ManagedIdentityAPI\ManagedIdentityWeb\Pages\Index.cshtml.cs:line
> 36    at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages.Infrastructure.ExecutorFactory.NonGenericTaskHandlerMethod.Execute(Object
> receiver, Object[] arguments)    at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages.Infrastructure.PageActionInvoker.InvokeHandlerMethodAsync()
> at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages.Infrastructure.PageActionInvoker.InvokeNextPageFilterAsync()
> at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages.Infrastructure.PageActionInvoker.Rethrow(PageHandlerExecutedContext
> context)    at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages.Infrastructure.PageActionInvoker.Next(State&
> next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
> at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages.Infrastructure.PageActionInvoker.InvokeInnerFilterAsync()
> at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeNextResourceFilter>g__Awaited|25_0(ResourceInvoker
> invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean
> isCompleted)    at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResourceExecutedContextSealed
> context)    at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Next(State&
> next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
> at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeFilterPipelineAsync>g__Awaited|20_0(ResourceInvoker
> invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean
> isCompleted)    at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeAsync>g__Awaited|17_0(ResourceInvoker
> invoker, Task task, IDisposable scope)    at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeAsync>g__Awaited|17_0(ResourceInvoker
> invoker, Task task, IDisposable scope)    at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware.<Invoke>g__AwaitRequestTask|6_0(Endpoint
> endpoint, Task requestTask, ILogger logger)    at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext
> context)    at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IIS.Core.IISHttpContextOfT`1.ProcessRequestAsync()

Any clue here for troubleshoot?

Comment: I don't think you can use Managed Identity locally.

Answer (score 1):

It's trying to use the AZ CLI there and its refresh token has expired. Run az login again in the command line and try again.

Comment: Error message has changed after a fresh az login. I updated it in above original thread.

Comment: Hmm, it could be that you are signed in to wrong tenant in AZ CLI. Try specifying the tenant ID with `az login -t id-here`

Comment: To get rid of this CLI, I deployed the Web App also in Azure. Now error message is different and very general.  I updated above loop with this additional info. Trying to find some specific info in it.

Comment: Well, we can't really help for a 500 error I think :\ That's an error in Microsoft's API endpoint.

Comment: Error not there once disabling managed identity security and token call,  then directly calling Web API endpoints. Is there a way we can find whether token access call reached to API side or it's breaking from Web UI side itself before reaching Web API?

Comment: I have the same error from the Azure Portal UI